# Mostrar hora de mi datetime ASP.NET CORE

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Intente obtener la **hora** de la siguiente forma.

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FechaConsulta.ToString("tt"))
```

Para obtener la **fecha** hice lo siguiente.

```
@Html.ValueFor(modelItem => item.FechaConsulta, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")
```

Recuerdo que hay una lista con con estos formatos, por si alguno sabe donde esta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
item.FechaConsulta.ToString("HH:mm"); // 07:00  este formato es de 24 horas
item.FechaConsulta.ToString("hh:mm tt");// 07:00 AM tt es para mostrar si es AM o PM formato 12 horas
```

Hola pruebe esto,
Saludos